# Windows Batch file to read a file and replace a string

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, replace, find

The file below contains 3 purchase orders.  The first line of each purchase order starts with a constant record identifier (which I put in **BOLD** letters):

850   00000000000

I need to search for string "***MC66F***" in each PO (which is italicized and in BOLD).  IF the string is found, then I need to replace the customer ID.  However, the customer ID "ABC00" is in ALL purchases orders.  The issue is I need to update the customer ID in ONLY that purchase order containing the string "MC66F" with "ABC04".

**850   00000000000**123ABC45              PO               ***ABC00***                         79       79       1        000056
850   BEG002000009 22123ABC45                                            20160909
850   CUR004000009  EUR
850   REF00400000CR ***MC66F***
850   DTM0170000013720160909
850   DTM0170000063 20160915
850   DTM0170000064 20160909
850   N1 04700000BY                                                               5450534000031
850   N1 04700000SU                                                               0728658000004
850   N1 04700000DP                                                               5450534002370
850   N1 04700000IV                                                               5450534005821
850   PO1083000001                   0000000000000002EA200000000000009118  SAB00D9KR6T6
850   PO1083000002                   0000000000000012EA200000000000015294  SAB0058FAEAS
**850   00000000000**456ABC45              PO               ABC00                         18132    18132    1        000056
850   BEG002000009 22456ABC45                                            20160909
850   CUR004000009  EUR
850   DTM0170000013720160909
850   DTM0170000063 20160914
850   DTM0170000064 20160909
850   N1 04700000BY                                                               5450534000017
850   N1 04700000SU                                                               608030938
850   N1 04700000DP                                                               0534002349
850   N1 04700000IV                                                               5450534005838
850   PO1083000001                   0000000000000001EA200000000000010518                                                    SAB00MYD9UP2
**850   00000000000**789ABC45              PO               ABC00                         18133    18133    1        000056
850   BEG002000009 22789ABC45                                            20160909
850   CUR004000009  EUR
850   DTM0170000013720160909
850   DTM0170000063 20160914
850   DTM0170000064 20160909
850   N1 04700000BY                                                               5450534000017
850   N1 04700000SU                                                               608030938
850   N1 04700000DP                                                               0534002332
850   N1 04700000IV                                                               5450534005838
850   PO1083000001                   0000000000000002EA200000000000010518                                                    SAB00MYD9UP2

Some things I have tried based on research (and how I would do it in UNIX) is store the lines in an array and then do an IF condition searching for the string in the array.  All I can do is get the array, but couldn't figure out how to utilize the IF condition.

```
    @echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%a in (%INPUTFILE%) do (
      set /A count+=1
      set "array[!count!]=%%a"
    )
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo !array[%%i]! >> %OUTPUTFILE%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDITS:

```
for %%b in (inputfile.*) do (

rem Process all input lines and create output file

(
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%%~fb) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   rem If new order starts
   if "!line:~0,17!" equ "850   00000000000" (
      rem show the previous one
      if defined firstLine (
         echo !firstLine!
         type thisOrder.txt
         del thisOrder.txt
     )
      rem and start new order
      set "firstLine=%%a"
   ) else (
      rem If the string was found in this order
      if "!line:%search%=!" neq "%%a" (
         rem replace the customer ID in first line
         set "firstLine=!firstLine:%old%=%new%!"
   )    
      rem Save this line in this order
      echo %%a>> thisOrder.txt
   )

)
echo !firstLine!
type thisOrder.txt
del thisOrder.txt

) > output.%RANDOM%.txt

)
```

I tried to generate a random number within the file since I thought it was just overwriting the file with each new iteration.  But this didn't work.  Seems it is outputting an extra "850 00000000000" segment at the beginning of the next PO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "firstLine="
del thisOrder.txt 2>NUL

rem Process all input lines and create output file
(
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   rem If new order starts
   if "!line:~0,15!" equ "850 00000000000" (
      rem show the previous one
      if defined firstLine (
         echo !firstLine!
         type thisOrder.txt
         del thisOrder.txt
      )
      rem and start new order
      set "firstLine=%%a"
   ) else (
      rem If the search string was found in this order
      if "!line:MC66F=!" neq "%%a" (
         rem replace the customer ID in first line
         set "firstLine=!firstLine:ABC00=ABC04!"
      )
      rem Save this line in this order
      echo %%a>> thisOrder.txt
   )
)
echo !firstLine!
type thisOrder.txt
del thisOrder.txt
) > output.txt
```

All working parameters are written literally in order to make the code clearer, but you may specify their values in variables or in parameters. For example, you may start the code with these lines:

```
set "search=MC66F"
set "old=ABC00"
set "new=ABC04"
```

... and then adjust the corresponding lines in the code; for example:

```
rem If the search string was found in this order
if "!line:%search%=!" neq "%%a" (
   rem replace the customer ID in first line
   set "firstLine=!firstLine:%old%=%new%!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think the copy/paste of my original text threw it off positionally, so I had to update the ~0,15 to ~0,18.  I also used your additional comment about specifying the values in variables and this worked great!  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Hi Aacini, I am running into an issue processing multiple files in a directory with this code.  I tried using a FOR loop, see original post with EDITS to see what I was shooting for.

Comment: Hi @Aacini, do you think you can help me out?

Comment: You forgot to include this line `set "firstLine="` _inside_ the `for` that process each file. You must also move `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line at beginning, _outside_ the `for`. Finally, if you have _several_ files named "inputfile" with different extensions (as your `inputfile.*` wild-card suggest), I suggest you to use _the same extension_ of the input files in each one of the output files: `) > output%%~xb`

Comment: Thanks, once again @Aacini!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it.

Steps:

- Reading the input file contents and storing it as environment variables (like you did it). It's one line per variable. The difference is that it uses some extra logic: it treats the file not like a sequence of lines, but as a sequence of orders, and each order is a sequence of records (a record is a line). So, the (`_ARRAY`) env var is *2 dimensional* (*0* based indexes):

  - 1st index is the order
  - 2nd index is the record (line) index inside the order

  The `_OLENGTHS` variable contains the last indexes (length - 1) of each order (*12 10 10* in our case), and it's used in the next phase.
- Processing the previously created env vars. It saves each order header (2nd index *0*) into another var to be altered later. Then it iterates trough the rest of that order's records, searching for the customer. If it finds it, it replaces it in the header. For string/pattern matching I used [findstr /?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).

  *Note*: I had to use labels because some nested variables expansion; this is the only way I could do it.
- Creating the output file and dumping the modified env vars content into it.

Notes:

- The code might be highly inefficient. I didn't spend any time optimizing it.
- It relies on the fact that each order starts with *850 00000000000*.
- It also relies on the fact that the customer record has the following format: *850 REF* followed by a sequence of digits and letters(upper + lower case), then a space and then the customer name.
- It relies that in the order record, the customer (that needs to be replaced) is the 4th token.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _INPUTFILE=in.txt
set _OUTPUTFILE=out.txt
set _OIDX=-1
set _RIDX=0
set _OLENGTHS=
set _RECORD=
set _HEADER=
set _IDMARK=850 00000000000
set _REFMARK=850 REF
set _CUSTOMER=MC66F
set _NEWCUSTOMER=ABC04

:: Read the inoput file contents and store it in env vars
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%_INPUTFILE%) do (
    echo %%f | findstr /b /c:"%_IDMARK%" 1>nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        set /a _OIDX+=1
        if "!_RECORD!" neq "" (
            set _OLENGTHS=!_OLENGTHS! !_RIDX!
        ) else (
            set _RECORD=_
        )
        set /a _RIDX=0
    ) else (
        set /a _RIDX+=1
    )
    set _ARRAY[!_OIDX!][!_RIDX!]=%%f
)
set _OLENGTHS=%_OLENGTHS% %_RIDX%

:: Do some processing on the env vars
set /a _OIDX=-1
for %%f in (%_OLENGTHS%) do (
    set /a _OIDX+=1
    call :set_header_var !_OIDX!
    for /l %%g in (1,1,%%f) do (
        call :process_record !_OIDX! %%g
    )
)

:: Dump all the env vars contents into the output file
copy nul %_OUTPUTFILE%
set /a _OIDX=-1
for %%f in (%_OLENGTHS%) do (
    set /a _OIDX+=1
    call :set_header_var !_OIDX!
    for /l %%g in (0,1,%%f) do (
        call :dump_var !_OIDX! %%g
    )
)

goto :eof

:process_record
    echo !_ARRAY[%1][%2]! | findstr /r /c:"^%_REFMARK%[0-9A-Za-z]* %_CUSTOMER%" 1>nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        call :alter_header %1
    )
    goto :eof

:set_header_var
    set _HEADER=!_ARRAY[%1][0]!
    goto :eof

:alter_header
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,*" %%h in ('echo !_HEADER!') do (
        set _ARRAY[%1][0]=%%h %%i %%j %_NEWCUSTOMER% %%l
    )
    goto :eof

:dump_var
    echo !_ARRAY[%1][%2]!>>%_OUTPUTFILE%
    goto :eof
```

After running it, the output file looks like the input file except for the 1st line which becomes:

> 850 00000000000123ABC45 PO **ABC04** 79 79 1 000056

**@EDIT0**: I didn't carefully read the requirement, i was replacing the customer (*ABC00*) by the string to search for (*MC66F*), instead of the new customer (*ABC04*). Corrected.

Comment: The output of the new first line is off positionally when the old record is compared to the new updated record.


OLD:`850   00000000000123ABC45              PO               ABC00                         18132    18132    1        000056      000004010004010X X4014010104010                              PP`

NEW:`850 00000000000123ABC45 PO MC66F 79       79       1        000056      000004010004010X X4014010104010`

The CUS ID I was looking to change it to was to ABC04. The search string was MC66F. The user @Aacini code seems to work as I hoped for. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
powershell -command "(gc -Delimiter %delim% %file%)
     -replace %regex0%, %replace0% 
     .....
     -replace %regexn%, %replacen%
     -join %delim% | Set-Content %newfile%"
```

*newline just for display